# Sinatra endpoint is working perfectly on localhost, but not found in production?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a weird issue i'm unable to troubleshoot, I get a 404 response body of

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
```

from my sinatra API when deployed on heroku, I have a hundred routes and all of them work fine, except this one. This one works in development...

```
namespace '/departments' do

  namespace '/department' do

    get '/single' do
      begin
        dept = API::Department.find(params['department_id'])
        status 200
        body json BODY: {
          department: dept.dept_details
        }
      rescue => error
        puts error
        status 403
        body json DETAIL: error
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Apparently in localhost you can nest namespaces inside each-other, but in production it doesn't work.

```
namespace '/departments' do

    get '/department' do
      begin
        dept = API::Department.find(params['department_id'])
        status 200
        body json BODY: {
          department: dept.dept_details
        }
      rescue => error
        puts error
        status 403
        body json DETAIL: error
      end
    end

end
```